# What is measure of angle $x$

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCDE$ is e regular pentagon and $FBC$ is a equaliteral triangle. What is measure of angle $x$

I didnt now how to find. Please help me. Thanku very much
[image]

Comment: Hint: $\triangle BFA$ is isosceles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since two different answers are posted, I will chime in:

$$\angle ABC = 108^\circ$$

$$\angle FBC = 60^\circ$$

$$\implies \angle FBA = 48^\circ$$
$$\angle BFA + \angle BAF =   180^\circ- 48^\circ = 132^\circ$$

And since $\triangle FBA$ is isosceles, 
$$\angle BFA + \angle BAF =\frac{132^\circ}{2}= 66^\circ$$

Comment: Thanky very much sir. Now i understand

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that  FBC is an equilateral triangle, we can deduce that  FBA is an isosceles triangle.

This plus the facts, that every interior angle in a regular pentagon measures 108° and every interior angle in a equilateral triangle measures 60° gives us the final result:

```
x = 66°
```

Comment: How find x=66, please told me, in detail form

Comment: Which is the asnwers correct, x=66 or x=84

Comment: ∠CBF = 60° and ∠CBA = 108° so ∠FBA has to be 48°.  Because the triangle FBA is an isosceles triangle we can deduce that BAF = \frac12 (180° - 48°) = 66°

Answer (score 0):

IFF (If and only if) these conditions are met

All Sides are the same size
therefore the equal angles to each angle in the regular rectangle are as follows:  (excluding the equilateral triangle)

```
360/5 = 72*
```

Add the variable y and make it
(Y is the angle that is the shortest in that triangle on the bottom right side of the regular pentagon)

```
72 - 60 = 12
```

now we know the new Variable Y, lets also conclude the second triangle is an iso-metric triangle.  Meaning 2 of its sides are equal.  Therefore:

```
180 - 12 = 2x
```

Since there are 2 same angles with the third angle known as 16* All we got to do now is solve for X:

```
180 - 12 = 168
168 = 2x

168/2 = 2x/2
x = 84
```

So X is 84 Degrees